# AppBar layout is covering everything

Tags: android-layout

I have a layout like this. The problem is the Appbar layout is on top of everything, i.e. it covers the `viewpage` (I have to use padding to shift a bit down) and `navigation` drawer.
How should I order this layout so that the `appbar` does not cover the other layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.xyz.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left_nav"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_black_24dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right_nav"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So, with this layout I am getting something like this:

[image]

See, the first planet is hidden below the `appbar`. Also, another problem is the left_nav should be below the navigation.

[image]

In the 2nd screenshot you can see the common fragments are also covered by `appbar` (in this map, the `mylocation` tab, which should be on top-right corner, is hidden by the `appbar`)

Comment: set top padding to the main activity layout  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

Comment: Thanks, but that will solve the position on y-coordinate. But in ideal situation, navigation should be drawn over the appbar, right/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a similar layout in one of my project and below code snippet works perfectly for me. Please try it out.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xyz.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dropshadow"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shop_custom_toolbar"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left_nav"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_black_24dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right_nav"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...working perfectly. Since you have done things with navigation drawer, may I ask you how you call the settings activity from navigation drawer?

Comment: @BaRud I've fetched it on click listener of list view item, that if setting exists then it will go to settings activity.